# JPA Criteria API Fetch Entities that have a specific Parent Property Value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a `User` and `UserRole` model, that looks like this:

`User.java`

```
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private UserRole role;

    //All other properties...

}
```

`UserRole.java`

```
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    //All other properties...

}
```

I need to be able to fetch all users that have `role = 1L`.

I'm able to do this with JPQL, as follows:

```
TypedQuery<SystemUser> query = entityManager.createQuery("Select u from User u left join u.role r where r.id=?1", User.class);
query.setParameter(1, roleId);
return query.getResultList();
```

However, for some reason, I would like to know if I can achieve the exact same thing **Without JPQL**, by simply using the JPA Criteria API.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks,
Sriram Sridharan

Comment: Your current query can be simplified. Join is not needed. You can use simply following: *Select u from User u where u.role.id=?1*

Comment: That's right! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code,

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> root = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);
criteriaQuery.where(builder.equal(root.get("role").get("id"), roleId));
return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)..getResultList();
```